# Oracle startup hangs after OS upgrade

Tags: linux, fedora, oracle-12c

I'm just upgraded My Fedora 25 to Fedora 27 using
       [Upgrading Fedora 26 Workstation to Fedora 27](https://fedoramagazine.org/upgrading-fedora-26-fedora-27/)

but after rebooting the system, now I can not start my Oracle DB.

I'm using Oracle 12.1.0.2

sqlplus startup command hangs (doing nothing even after a long time)

also dbca hangs and not starting

I've have googled for tow days with no help. and now looking assist from you guys

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know (haven't tested yet) Fedora 26 and 27 ships with glibc version which is incompatible with the Oracle software. The relinking of the Oracle home went fine but "startup nomount" hangs. You can check this out - https://www.dizwell.com/wordpress/atlas-a-universal-oracle-preinstaller/atlas-installing-oracle-on-fedora-23/